# Using laravel-menu, how do I get sub-items to nest?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using [Lavary's laravel-menu package](https://github.com/lavary/laravel-menu#sub-items), and I am trying to build a simple 2 level menu system based on the contents of a db table. I have the middleware created to create the menu on each request:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    Menu::make('NavBar', function($menu){
        $menuitems = MenuItem::all();
        foreach($menuitems as $menuitem)
        {
            if(!is_null($menuitem->parent)){
               // For example, 'Conferences', a top level menu item with a null parent field
               $menu->add($menuitem->title, url($menuitem->url));
            }
            else{
                // Parent is a field in database, for example 'Traverse City 2015' would have the parent 'conferences'
                $parent = $menuitem->parent;
                $menu->item($parent)->add($menuitem->title, url($menuitem->url));

            }
        }
    });
    return $next($request);
}
```

In my view, I call:

```
{!! $NavBar->asUl() !!}
```

I would expect this to render as such:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="/conferences">Conferences</a></li>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/conferences/traverse-city-2015">Traverse City 2015</li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Instead, it is rendering:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="/conferences/">Conferences</a></li>
  <li><a href="/conferences/traverse-city-2015">Traverse City 2015</a></li>
</ul>
```

Any ideas why the sub-items aren't showing up correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are after is nested groups: https://github.com/lavary/laravel-menu#nested-groups

```
Menu::make('MyNavBar', function($menu){
    $menu->group(array('prefix' => 'pages', 'data-info' => 'test'), function($m){

        $m->add('About', 'about');

        $m->group(array('prefix' => 'about', 'data-role' => 'navigation'), function($a){

            $a->add('Who we are', 'who-we-are?');
            $a->add('What we do?', 'what-we-do');
            $a->add('Our Goals', 'our-goals');
        });
    });

});
```

This will then render as:

```
<ul>
    <li data-info="test">
    <a href="http://yourdomain.com/pages/about">About</a>
        <ul>
            <li data-info="test" data-role="navigation"><a href="http://yourdomain.com/pages/about/who-we-are"></a></li>
            <li data-info="test" data-role="navigation"><a href="http://yourdomain.com/pages/about/what-we-do"></a></li>
            <li data-info="test" data-role="navigation"><a href="http://yourdomain.com/pages/about/our-goals"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Using your snippet, my project is rendering <ul><li>About</li><li>Who we are</li><li>What we do?</li><li>Our Goals</li></ul>, which is honestly the problem my code is having, as the documentation for sub-items says it should work.

Comment: Hm, I am seeing both the issue you posted and, some time ago this issue: https://github.com/lavary/laravel-menu/issues/91 . It looks like the feature may not be working, and on top of that there has been no activity on the repo for about 3 months. It might be time to fork it and fix it yourself, or find an alternative package.

Comment: Fixed since february '16: https://github.com/lavary/laravel-menu/issues/91#issuecomment-182247847 Update to latest version of lavary.